# How to add remove Parent control dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following controls:

```
<UserControl >

   <!--<ScrollViewer >-->
       <Viewbox >
           <Canvas/>
       </Viewbox>
   <!--</ScrollViewer>-->

</UserControl>
```

I want to add and remove dynamically the `ScrollViewer` as my `ViewBox` parent (for example when I click a `Button`):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here add or remove ScrollViewer
}
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `UserControl` is named `userControl`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = userControl.Content as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        var content = scrollViewer.Content;
        scrollViewer.Content = null;
        userControl.Content = content;
    }
    else
    {
        var content = userControl.Content;
        userControl.Content = null;
        userControl.Content = new ScrollViewer { Content = content };
    }
}
```

Why set the `Content` to `null`, you might wonder?  Because WPF won't let you have one element be the child of two elements at once, and immediately throws an exception if you try to do that (e.g. by just saying `userControl.Content = scrollViewer.Content;`).